# How to defeat the Stalker solo as a Rhino?

Tags: pc, warframe

I'm a reactor'd level 30 Rhino with high shields, health, and around 1400 damage block on my Iron Skin.
I use the Karak, Lex, and Galatine as weapons.
The only other ability I use is Rhino Stomp. All my abilities cost half of the base energy price.
I have faced the Stalker two times using this build, and have been absolutely destroyed each time, soloing. I am prepared to build energy and health restores. How can I defeat him?

Answer (score 2):

I am a fellow Rhino user, and I am going to give you some tips. First, Iron Skin is pointless against the Stalker. He can use an ability called Dispel which removes all Buffs of Warframes. This includes but is not limited to Hysteria, Blessing, and Iron Skin.

First, tips on the primary. If you are rank 6 or higher, you should invest in a Soma or a Penta. They are some of the best non-clan re-search items. Penta does massive blast damage, and the Soma does massive crit damage (30% crit chance base). My Soma can destroy him in a matter of seconds. If you spend the time and effort and get the weapon by the name of Boltor Prime, a 4 forma build can destroy almost any enemy in a matter of seconds. Just maximize its damage (I use Serration, Split Chamber, then 3 of a certain element (using event mods and nightmare mods)). You can achieve over 700 damage per hit.

Lex can be replaced with the Stug possibly, it can do massive damage if the rounds hit. Or the Acrid if you can get it from a Dojo.

(OLD INFO)
The Galitine though, is amazing if used correctly. It has a base 400 Charge damage, which with the right mods, can exceed 1200 damage per charge hit (it also has a base 25% crit chance when charge attacking). Then, if you put magnetic damage ( it has a 50% status chance when charge attacking) it could easily remove his shields (or viral to deal with his health). http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Galatine

Due to the removal of charge attacks, you will have to find a different weapon. Unless you have a high Damage channel build, I would not suggest using your melee against Stalker or any of the other random bosses.

Now, your abilities. Iron Skin is nearly useless (you can use it block a single attack). Roar is also very useful. If you have enough power strength, it can boost over 50% bonus damage (with weapons only). Stomp will do some damage, but he will not be stunned. 
http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Roar

Besides what I said, try and play with other players who know what they are doing. If you are alone, keep your distance, shoot every once and a while, and do not be in a rush to finish him off.

Comment: Why did this get downvotes, I don't know. It's a solid answer. +1 from me.